# I already have a library that is in Python 2.3. Is there any advantage to rewriting it to 2.6?

Tags: python

Or, should we have a virutal environment and continue to run this on 2.3?

Comment: Does it really need rewriting to run on 2.6?

Comment: A possible candidate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I take it back; porting between different 2.x versions is not trivial. Note that `raise "Oops"` worked in 2.5 but not in 2.6. However, the port should be pretty easy; for one thing, I believe that anything that would break in version `n+1` will warn in `n`, so you should be able to step through the versions. Alternatively, just change over and let your test suite catch everything =).

Given the choice, you might as well rewrite to Python 2.7, which is the latest (and final) 2.x version.

---

Here are the things that I can find that might break, from looking at the docs ([2.6](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html), [2.5](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html), [2.4](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/whatsnew/node12.html)):

- Previously valid variable names are now reserved keywords:

  ```
  with
  as
  ```
- Some builtins are shadowed:

  ```
  set
  frozenset
  reversed
  sorted
  bytes
  ```
- You can no longer `raise` a string.

There are probably others.

Comment: I've come across one old Python program that used `as` as a variable name (which became a reserved word somewhere around 2.5/2.6). Easy to fix, though.

Comment: In short, though, the probability of needing to do any modifications of good code is low.

Answer (score 1):

You need to weigh up the pros and cons of doing the port

2.5/6/7 gives you better programming structures, more libraries, etc.
but you won't know how much work is involved with the port until you try it.

I would imagine it's worthwhile spending say a day or two on the port
If you feel you are getting nowhere after that time, careful reconsider whether the advantages will still make the port worth doing